# android,working while thread

Tags: android, multithreading

---

i am working on application in which i want to frequently change four imageviews images while thread is sleeping .

---

is it possible for doing ui changes while thread sleeps for two seconds.?

---

or there is another way to doing my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chirag , You can invoke another new thread that does that(i.e. change your images) , this new child thread will be invoked just before you call Thread.sleep().By this approach you can be sure that both the threads are synchronous.

Comment: thanks but i think than it will be more complex bcoz of thread synchronization and my code is already complex so pls if you have another way for it.

Comment: if you think that's complex then instead of using sleep() use a Timer that counts 2 seconds & then after 2 secs start your next method while in the meantime of 2 secs update your UI

Comment: chirag I don't see any such way to make a method run as the thread sleeps.But well you can give a try to BroadcastReciever which will be sent just before thread sleep()

Comment: thanks buddy for your help.i finally do it with thread.as you suggest first.

Answer (score 1):

While thread is in sleep mode, you cannot do that.But your question is the answer here.you can
update the UI with images for every 2 seconds.This is what effectively happens when you say Thread.sleep(2000)
and after that period of time you can update your UI.

Comment: sorry i cant understand pls give me detailed explanation.thanks for your reply